# Post (Error in deserializing body of request message for operation)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "foo",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ResultChange Foo(int bar, String foobar);
```

I've downloaded a Firefox plugin (Poster) so I can easily send POST request.

But I get the

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Error in deserializing body of request message for
>   operation 'ChangeDetails'. The OperationFormatter could not
>   deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is
>   empty (IsEmpty = true).'.

I've set the style to Wrapped  as you can see, but that did not solve my issue. This was a solution provided here: [Bad Request Error On REST service Method call with POST (json Data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325516/bad-request-error-on-rest-service-method-call-with-post-json-data) but did not solve it.

**Update**: I've succesfully sent a test() function, and it sent me back:  "OK, the service is working". as it returns a string with that content.

What can I do to fix my issue?

Comment: did you ever get this problem solved?